# sci-fi short story: humans invent force field but meet weird death because it blocks God's view?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A sci-fi short story I recall from my childhood, where scientists are working on a force shield or giant force "bubble" and the leader of the team goes insane when considering the ramifications of the probably perfect reflective properties and raves about the dangers of blocking God's view. But the work proceeds without/ despite him, and story comes to a bizarre end (spoiler):

> when shield is powered up everyone freezes in place, dust gathers over a timeless period, and roots sprout from the bodies.

Comment: And your childhood was . . . 5 years ago? 50 years ago?

Comment: This has echoes of Asimov's "Breeds There a Man?" but it is clearly not the same story.

Comment: I read it around the early 80s. I think it was one of a collection of short short stories.

Comment: ... and now that I've reviewed "Breeds There a Man" I think I'm munging two stories together. Probably both in the same collection which was grouped by tropes, e.g time travel, black holes, etc... and... force fields/shields and the like. So "Breeds There" is a partial answer, thanks! But what was the other one... God's view being blocked and the weird ending? I'll probably find it in same collection with Asimov's story.

Comment: My googling of the related terms found another contemporary story, including the force shield trope and exploration of God-like powers: "Microcosmic God"... very cool.

Comment: @gdeff is that the one with the banana fiber inventor with the micro creatures with cocaine body chemistry he invents?